# Assign Enum Class to a variable and access it

Tags: python, enums

I have a Enum Class

```
default_enums.py

import enum

class Color(enum.Enum):
    Red = 0
    Blue = 1
    Green = 2

app.py

from default_enums import Color

def set_enums():
    global color_enum
    color_enum = Color


another_file.py

import app

#this line throws the error
# RuntimeError: no object bound to color_enum
app.color_enum.Red
```

I am not able to access the value from color_enum, as i have already assigned the class to color_enum.

Can anyone help me in solving the issue.

Thanks

Comment: " as i have already assigned the class to color_enum." No, you never did that. You never actually call the function `def set_enums`...

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call the `set_enums()` function in the app.py module.

```
-----------app.py-----------

from default_enums import Color

def set_enums():
    global color_enum
    color_enum = Color

#call the function to set the value for color_enum 
set_enums()

-----------another_file.py-----------

from app import *

print(color_enum.Red.value)
#0
```

Though this woks, I feel the design code could be improved upon. Infact the whole `app.py` module in itself is not required. And the `color_enum` variable is not defined previously, but is set up in the `set_enums()` function, which can lead to problems like the ones you faced.

So I would suggest looking at the code design once again, rather than implementing above design.

Comment: “There are two ways of constructing a software design. One way is to make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies. And the other way is to make it so complicated that there are no obvious deficiencies.”
 - C.A.R. Hoare